# Sample vector containing 1 and 0s such that the sum of the vector is Poisson distributed

Tags: sampling, poisson-distribution

I want to sample a vector containing $1$ and $0$s such that the sum of the vector is sampled from a poisson distribution.

With regards to generating such a vector, my restraints are to sample some vector once and apply vectorised operations thereafter. How would I do this? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The sum of poison random variables is also poisson.  If you picked a $\lambda$ small enough, you would have higher probability of sampling 0 or 1.

Comment: Could you expand on that @DemetriPananos?

Comment: Ah legend, very smart, thanks!